# application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: is called before the prompt

Tags: ios, ios9

During the initial app installation everything works as exptected: **application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:** is called after the prompt *"*APP* Would Like To Send You Push Notifications"* is accepted or rejected. But if the app is deleted, and reinstalled again I'm getting a weird behaviour: that delegate method is called **BEFORE** user had a chance to accept or reject the prompt, right after it appears...

In my app I need to perform some UI action after a user accepts or rejects that prompt, and I don't see any other option other than using the above delegate method (and it seems not to work after re-install)

Any help is greatly appreciated.